# Layer Partly missing after zoom in the map and download from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, display, download, sentinel-1

I want to calculate DpRVIc (a kind of vegetation index) by using the Sentinel-1 data on Google Earth Engine. I successfully done my calculation and added the layer to the map on GEE website. However, when I zoomed in the map, the layer was partly missing. I also downloaded the layer and opened it by QGIS but the layer was still partly missing.

**Here is my code on GEE: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a846139b9421782dbe09d6f2aefbd999**

**Here is my downloaded files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V1Z_dfH_FcnvDMv3fTTsDu8TzM53X-5i?usp=sharing**

**Here is the example of partly missing layer:**

1. Region of interested (Taiwan2 in green)
   [image: Region of interested (Taiwan2 in green)]
2. Add the layer to map
   [image]
3. Layer missing after zooming in
   [image]
4. Layer missing after downloading and open it by using QGIS
   [image]

**What I have done for testing:**

1. Do the same process multiple times, the missing part is still the same.
2. Wait some time for GEE to display the layer (about 1 hour), Still missing.
3. Wait some time for GEE to load the layer (about 1 hour) before downloading it. Still missing.
4. Makes the `MaxPixels` larger in the function `Export.image.toDrive()`. The downloaded layer is still missing.
5. Do the same process but change my region of interested inside the missing part (red). Everything works! No missing when zooming in, no missing after downloading.
   [image]
   [image]
6. Try different region of interested, not all of them have the same issue (Taiwan3 ~ Taiwan5)

**What I need for help:**

1. Why the layer on GEE partly missing after zooming in and downloading? Any way to solve it?
2. What can I do if I want to download the layer for whole Taiwan at once, rather than split Taiwan into multiple strips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem stems from using `filtered.first()` in the `day_mosaics` function.  You are copying a bunch of stuff from the first image, including the footprint, regardless of how much of that image covers the region.  You're essentially lying to the system about the extent of the mosaic and then complaining that the extent isn't what you expected.

You should essentially never touch system:footprint and definitely don't set it manually. If you need to get a geometry, use `image.geometry()`, and set a geometry with `image.clip()`.  But in this case, you should be clipping the mosaic with the ROI, not some random image's geometry.  Similarly, you probably shouldn't be blindly copying the rest of the metadata from the first image either.  Instead, set real, meaningful values (you definitely shouldn't be trying to set `system:version`; that makes no sense).

It's also not a good idea to use `iterate` here, a list to collect the mosaics, or the `If()` function; instead, just map over the dates and filter out empties at the end (either set a `size` property or filter on `system:band_names` using `contains` for some band that should exist).

Or better, rather than making a mosaic for every possible day, many of which wont exist, get the list of distinct, actual days from the collection to begin with and map over those directly.

```
var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filterDate(ref_start, ref_end)
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING')) 
        .select('VV','VH','angle')
        .sort('system:time_start', false)
        .filterBounds(ROI)
        .map(function(image) {
            return image.set('date', image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
        })

var dates = S1.aggregate_array('date').distinct()
print(dates)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Learn a lesson :)